# how to find out in which direction was the phone tilted in android

Tags: android

i am making an Android application in which i need to find out in which direction the user is shaking is phone. Not tilting, i mean literally jerking his hand in the direction of.

Actually i am making a photo viewing application and i wish to know if he has jerked his phone to the right then the next image should load up and if it is left movement , then the previous image should load up.

how do i achieve this. Currently to detect a shake i am using [this](http://www.clingmarks.com/?p=25) tutorial.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article. I have not tried it personally but looks good to me.

http://www.codeshogun.com/blog/2009/04/17/how-to-detect-shake-motion-in-android-part-i/

You could adapt the motion detection calculation to actually determine the direction quite easily.

Comment: this is the same thing i am using, but it does not tell me anything reagarding in which direction was my phone moved. i have used the same calculation as given in the link but they only detect if the phone was shaked.